# Set ID for structs based on the current highest ID

Tags: c, struct

I need to keep the ID's of my structs organized as I create them.

It's a little difficult to explain so here's an example of what I'm doing

---

1 2 3 4       //Starting with an array of structs with ID's 1, 2, 3, and 4

1 2 4         //We remove the struct with the ID of 3

1 2 4 5       //add a new struct with an ID of 5, because a struct with an ID of 4 exists

1 2           //However, once we remove 4 and 5...

1 2 3         //we add a new struct, but this time with an ID of 3, because the highest ID is 2

---

I'm planning to have thousands of structs, and all the idea's I have had for implementing this have been too inefficient. 
If an existing algorithm that does this exists, what is it/what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a linked list. The ID can then easiliy be determined in the way you're describing by taking the id of the last instance in the list + 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int id;
    int attr1;
    struct MyStruct *next;

} mystruct_t;

void addItem(mystruct_t **head, int *len, int attr1);
void removeItem(mystruct_t **head, int *len, int id);
void printAllIds(mystruct_t *head);

void addItem(mystruct_t **head, int *len, int attr1)
{
    len++;
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(mystruct_t));
        (*head)->id = 1;
        (*head)->attr1 = attr1;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        mystruct_t *pointer = *head;
        while(pointer->next != NULL)
        {
            pointer = pointer->next;
        }
        pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(mystruct_t));
        pointer->next->id = pointer->id + 1;
        pointer->next->attr1 = attr1;
        pointer->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

void removeItem(mystruct_t **head, int *len, int id)
{
    mystruct_t *pointer = *head;
    mystruct_t *previous;
    while((pointer->id != id) && (pointer != NULL))
    {
        previous = pointer;
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    if(pointer == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    len--;
    if(pointer == *head)
    {
        mystruct_t *next = (*head)->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = next;
    }
    else if(pointer->next == NULL)
    {
        previous->next = NULL;
        free(pointer);
    }
    else
    {
        previous->next = pointer->next;
        free(pointer);
    }
}

void printAllIds(mystruct_t *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    mystruct_t *pointer = head;
    while(pointer != NULL)
    {
        char string[64];
        snprintf(string, 64, "%d ", pointer->id);
        printf(string);
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    mystruct_t *head = NULL;
    int len = 0;

    addItem(&head, &len, 1);
    addItem(&head, &len, 2);
    addItem(&head, &len, 3);
    addItem(&head, &len, 4);
    printAllIds(head);
    removeItem(&head, &len, 3);
    printAllIds(head);
    addItem(&head, &len, 5);
    printAllIds(head);
    removeItem(&head, &len, 4);
    removeItem(&head, &len, 5);
    printAllIds(head);
    addItem(&head, &len, 6);
    printAllIds(head);

    return 1;
}
```

Maybe there are shorter ways of doing this but this is just my 2 cents on the matter.

Comment: The solution is correct, although not in the language tagged by the question

Comment: Damn, I was answering all those python questions a few minutes ago, give me 2 seconds I will change it to C.

Comment: Thank you @Anteino ! I know enough about python to translate it myself! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yea but it would look stupid on this post and I could use the practise. Also I read your comment after completing it in C anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a variable to count the ID's as you create them, for instance in your scenario the count would be at 4 therefore, when you create a new struct the logic would be something to the effect of

```
structID = count + 1; //Create new ID
count++; //Increment the count
```

Comment: Only incrementing the counter does not help with step 5

Answer (score 0):

Either you would have a mean to reach all the struct with ID with one loop ( like a linked list ), the top/head element would be the latest added one (thus having the `ID = previous ID + 1`)

```
Initial state (top is 4)
4->3->2->1
Remove 3 (top is 4)
4->2->1
Add one (top is 5)
5->4->2->1
Remove 4 & 5 top is 2
2->1
Add one (top is 3)
3->2->1
```

Another approach would be to keep bitmap of the IDs (example with 8bit unsigned int),
This implementation would be more costly and complex as you might need to grow your bitfield along with the number of struct.

```
Initial state ( 1 << (4 - 1) | 1 << (3 - 1) | 1 << (2 - 1) | 1 << (1 - 1) )
00001111
remove 3 ( 1 << (4 - 1) | 1 << (2 - 1) | 1 << (1 - 1) )
00001011
add one ( 1 << (5- 1) | 1 << (4 - 1) | 1 << (2 - 1) | 1 << (1 - 1) )
00011011
remove 4 and 5 ( 1 << (2 - 1) | 1 << (1 - 1) )
00000011
add one ( 1 << (3 - 1) | 1 << (2 - 1) | 1 << (1 - 1) )
```

I would recommend the first approach.